# object.entries in ES5/Vanila javascript

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a below object.

```
{name: 'Ryan', Height: '5.6cm'}
```

in ES6 we have `Object.prototype.entries()` which would return key pair value in form of array. Also for `Object.prototype.values()` would return array of values.

Can anyone please help me on how to achieve samething in ES5 javascript  without using `Object.entries` and without using `Object.values()` ?

Comment: `Object.keys()` is ES5 afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sirko [answered this with his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596017/object-entries-in-es5-vanila-javascript#comment112457754_63596017), you can use Object.keys() to replace Object.entries():

```
var entriesObj = {name: 'Ryan', Height: '5.6cm'};
// var output = Object.entries(entriesObj).reduce((collector, [key, value]) => {
var output = Object.keys(entriesObj).reduce(function (collector, key) {
  var value = entriesObj[key];
  return Object.assign({}, collector, {
    [key]: 'modified' + value,
  });
}, {});
console.log(output); // {name: "modifiedRyan", Height: "modified5.6cm"}
```

For some reason my PhantomJS build doesn't have Object.entries but has Object.assign. You might also be able to use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate through an object properties (I think this one was the oldest approach).

Comment: Please be aware that the for..in approach includes properties from the prototype, which all the object methods don't do.
To get the same result you need to check `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` for each key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a polyfill library like core.js to import the polyfills you want to use, then you can just use ES6 methods in your code.

If you just want a one-off function, you can also find the polyfills on eg. MDN.

For `Object.prototype.entries()` this would give:

```
if (!Object.entries) {
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];
    
    return resArray;
  };
}
```

You could change it a little to your own function name if you don't want to add it to the Object scope.