# group object keys with the same value

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var myObject = {"audi": "gas", "tesla": "electric", "bmw": "electric", "mercedes": "electric"}
```

and I want to group all keys with same value in one string like using only es5

```
tesla bmw mercedes: electric. audi: gas
```

I used combination of `Object.keys` and `Object.values` but it didn't work for me

```
var res = ''
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key) {
    Object.values(myObject).map(function(val) {
        if (myObject[key] === val) {
            kes = {
                [res.concat(key)]: val
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Since this wouldn’t be valid a JavaScript object, do you want it as a string? Maybe you want the value to become the key with an array of the original keys with the value?

Comment: That could also work

Comment: Get one of the many _"group array of objects by property"_ questions/answers, swap property and value. You then have to convert the resulting (or intermediate) object into your requested string (`Object.entries()` + `.map()` + `.join()`)

Comment: Btw `Object.values` is not part of the ES5 specification afaik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would make more sense to group by 'fuel'. For that, you can use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

In the snippet a few different roads to Rome ...

[See also...](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fmhfcy?file=index.js)

```js
const logElem = document.querySelector(`pre`);
var myObject = {
  audi: "gas",
  tesla: "electric",
  bmw: "electric",
  mercedes: "electric"
};

const byFuel = Object.entries(myObject)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
    ({ ...acc, [value]: (acc[value] || []).concat(key) }), {});

logElem.textContent = `***By fuel (ES6)***\n ${
  JSON.stringify(byFuel, null, 2)}`;

// to swap keys and values from [byFuel]
const byCars = Object.entries(byFuel)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc,
    [value.join(`,`)]: key
  }), {});

logElem.textContent += `\n\n***By cars from byFuel (ES6)***\n${
  JSON.stringify(byCars, null, 2)}`;

// Use one reducer (ES6)
const byCarsInOne = Object.entries(myObject)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    const keysAggregatedAsSingleKey = Object.keys(myObject)
      .filter( key => myObject[key] === value )
      .join(`,`);
    return acc[keysAggregatedAsSingleKey] 
      ? acc 
      : { ...acc, [keysAggregatedAsSingleKey]: value };
  }, {});

logElem.textContent += `\n\n***One reducer***\n${
  JSON.stringify(byCarsInOne, null, 2)}`;


// ES5 (really necessary? All modern browsers support es6)
var byFuelEs5 = {};
var byCarsEs5 = {};

for (var key in myObject) {
  var ky = myObject[key];
  byFuelEs5[ky] = ky in byFuelEs5 
    ? byFuelEs5[ky].concat(key) 
    : [key];
}

logElem.textContent += `\n\n***ES5***\n${
  JSON.stringify(byFuelEs5, null, 2)}`;

for (var key in byFuelEs5) {
  byCarsEs5[byFuelEs5[key].join(`,`)] = key;
}

logElem.textContent += `\n\n${
  JSON.stringify(byCarsEs5, null, 2)}`;

// Object.keys ES5, not very efficient
// (makes you *really* want to use ES6 ;)
var cars = Object.keys(myObject);
var byCarsEs5_2 = cars
  .map( function(key) {return [myObject[key], key]; })
  .map( function(kv) {
    var fuel = kv[0];
    var comma = this[fuel] ? "," : "";
    this[fuel] = (this[fuel] || "") + comma + kv[1];
    return this; }, {} )
  .map( function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj)
      .map( key => this[obj[key]] = key );
    return this;
  }, {}).shift();
  
logElem.textContent += `\n\n***Object.keys and map ES5***\n${
      JSON.stringify(byCarsEs5_2, null, 2)}`;

// Finally, reduce from Object.keys my be more efficient
var byCarsEs5_3 = cars
  .reduce( function(acc, car) {
    var fuel = myObject[car];
    
    if (!~acc.fuels.indexOf(fuel)) {
      acc.fuels.push(fuel);
      var carsByFuel = cars.filter(key => myObject[key] === fuel);
      acc.result[carsByFuel] = fuel;
    }

    return acc; 
  }, {fuels: [], result: {}} ).result;

logElem.textContent += `\n\n***ES5 one reducer from  Object.keys***\n${
  JSON.stringify(byCarsEs5_3, null, 2)}`;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: nice, but there is a note in the question that says to use only es5

Comment: That's a great answer. I could work it by replacing `object.entries` by `Object.keys` based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363171/6771841

Comment: @Ndx see bottom of the edited snippet ... not that I would advise it, but still: ES5 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you (IE compatible)?

```js
var myObject = {
  "audi": "gas",
  "tesla": "electric",
  "bmw": "electric",
  "mercedes": "electric"
};

var reverseObject = Object.keys(myObject).reduce(function(result, car) {
  var type = myObject[car], list = result[type];
  if (!list) result[type] = list = [];
  list.push(car);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(reverseObject);

var result = Object.keys(reverseObject).map(function(type) {
  return reverseObject[type].join(" ") + ": " + type;
}).join(".");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this answer too. very clean and less code. it worked great too

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myObject = {audi: "gas", "tesla": "electric", bmw: "electric", "mercedes": "electric"};

var helper = Object.entries(myObject).reduce((helperObj,item) => {
  var key = item[0];
  var val = item[1];
  if(val in helperObj) {
     helperObj[val].push(key)
  } else {
    helperObj[val] = [key];
  }
  return helperObj;
}, {});

var res = Object.entries(helper).reduce((theRes,item) => {
  var fuel = item[0];
  var cars = item[1];
  var resKey = cars.join(' ');
  theRes[resKey] = fuel;
  return theRes;
}, {});

console.log(res)
```